BLE notification issue on Google Pixel and Samsung Galaxy devices
Description:
I am experiencing an issue with BLE notifications on certain devices, specifically Google Pixel and Samsung Galaxy models. The problem occurs when receiving a response that is longer than the MTU size, causing it to be split into two parts. On these devices, I only receive the second part of the message.
When initiating communication with the BLE device, we first do the discoverServices() and set the MTU to 512.
After that we send an initial message through a specific BluetoothGattCharacteristic.
Then, we expect to receive a JSON response from the device split into two parts due to its length. However, on Google Pixel and Samsung Galaxy devices, only the second part of the message is received (the method onCharacteristicChanged is invoked only once on the devices mentioned, meanwhile that is invoked twice on the rest of the devices we have tested).
The issue was detected with Android 14 and tested with the brand-new Android 15, but it has not been solved with the new OS update.
Any clue about what can be causing this behaviour? I have attached a code snippet below:
Code:
// STEP 1 - Connect to the BluetoothDevice
fun connect(device: BluetoothDevice, context: Context) {
    try {
        device.connectGatt(context, false, callback)
    } catch (e: SecurityException) {
        Log.d("Error connecting to ${device.address}")
    }
}

private val callback = object : BluetoothGattCallback() {
    // STEP 2 - Request the services after a successful connection
    override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int, newState: Int) {
        try {
            val deviceAddress = gatt.device.address
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                        gatt.discoverServices()
                    }
                } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                    disconnect()
                }
            } else {
                disconnect(status)
            }
        } catch (e: SecurityException) {
            Log.d("onConnectionStateChange: Error occurred $e")
        }
    }
    // STEP 3 - MTU request after a successful discoverServices()
    override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int) {
        try {
            with(gatt) {
                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    requestMtu(512)
                } else {
                    disconnect()
                }
            }
        } catch (e: SecurityException) {
            Log.d("onServicesDiscovered: Error occurred $e")
        }
    }
    // STEP 4 - Send message after setting the MTU properly
    override fun onMtuChanged(gatt: BluetoothGatt, mtu: Int, status: Int) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            deviceBluetoothGatt!!.services?.firstOrNull { it.uuid == serviceUUID.uuid }?.let { service ->
                val characteristic = service.characteristics.first { it.uuid == readCharacteristicUUID }
                try {
                    deviceBluetoothGatt!!.findCharacteristic(characteristic.uuid)?.let { _ ->
                        val payload = when {
                            characteristic.isIndicatable() -> BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE
                            characteristic.isNotifiable() -> BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE
                            else -> error("${characteristic.uuid} doesn't support notifications/indications")
                        }

                        characteristic.getDescriptor(configurationCharacteristicUUID)?.let { cccDescriptor ->
                            if (!deviceBluetoothGatt!!.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true)) {
                                return
                            }
                            cccDescriptor.value = payload
                            deviceBluetoothGatt!!.writeDescriptor(cccDescriptor)
                        } ?: this@BLEManager.run {
                            Log.e("${characteristic.uuid} doesn't contain the CCC descriptor!")
                        }
                    } ?: this@BLEManager.run {
                        Log.e("Cannot find $characteristic.uuid! Failed to enable notifications.")
                    }
                } catch (e: SecurityException) {
                    Log.d("onMtuChanged: Error occurred: $e")
                }
            }
        } else {
           Log.d("onMtuChanged: Error occurred $e")
           disconnect()
        }
    }
    // STEP 5 - Receive the message on this callback in blocks
    override fun onCharacteristicChanged(gatt: BluetoothGatt, characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic) {
        with(characteristic) {
            decodeResponse(characteristic.value)
        }
    }
    override fun onDescriptorWrite(gatt: BluetoothGatt, descriptor: BluetoothGattDescriptor, status: Int) {
        with(descriptor) {
            when (status) {
                BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS -> {
                    writeCharacteristic(GetinfoRequest().encode())
                }
                BluetoothGatt.GATT_WRITE_NOT_PERMITTED -> {
                    Log.d("Write not permitted for $uuid!")
                }
                else -> {
                    Log.d("Descriptor write failed for $uuid, error: $status")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Additional Information:

Android versions tested: Android 14, Android 15
Devices affected: Google Pixel 6A, Galaxy Tab S8


Welcome to Stack Overflow. In onMtuChanged() your code does not check for the negotiated MTU. Android 14 changed the behavior

Hi Risto! Thanks for your quick reply. You're right, the code I provided is not checking for the negotiated MTU. I've debugged it and I can confirm that I get a 517 value on the onMtuChanged method. This should not be the problem I guess. Nonetheless, I cannot see the connection with not checking the value received and the fact that we lose the first message. Does this make sense to you? Thanks in advance.

As questions about MTU come up here from time to time, I remembered this answer, and as far as I understand it, the new behaviour may be more compliant with the specification, but it may not always work better.

If the device was already connected to the phone at the time you call connectGatt() and a non-default mtu has previously been negotiated, then the onMtuChanged will be called immediately, possibly before your service discovery has completed. You should handle this case.

Thanks for the recommendations. Any idea about the topic of my question about losing the first message on some Android devices?
